# when insert new data in MySQL display notification in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I try to 
developed a simple android application view message from Mysql db in notification
My question is if i want to get information from the db every 2 mins or check if any new data has been posted to the db how i could this be done in android?
I tray several times with this code but the result was always the nothing lick image 
[Frem explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QEjp.png)
[from android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrVMx.png)
Note: The database is working
sev_data class :

```
  public class sev_data extends IntentService {
public static boolean ServiceIsRun = false;
public sev_data() {
    super("MyWebRequestService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    while (ServiceIsRun) {
        int id_s=0;
        String url0 = ""http://172.17.100.2/sendapp.php?co>"+id_s;
        String  msg;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url0);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            msg = Stream2String(in);
            in.close();
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(msg);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("date");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id= jsonObject.optString("id");
                String title = jsonObject.optString("title");
                String mess = jsonObject.optString("mess");
                 }
            // creat new intent
            intent = new Intent();
            //set the action that will receive our broadcast
            intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
            // add data to the bundle
            intent.putExtra("msg", msg);
            // send the data to broadcast
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            //delay for 50000ms
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        }catch (Exception ex){}
    }
}
String date="";
public String Stream2String(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader bureader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line ;
    String Text="";
    try{
        while((line=bureader.readLine())!=null) {
            Text+=line;
        }
        inputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception ex){}
    return Text;
}
```

}

sendapp.php :

```js
<?php
$hostname_mus_db = "localhost";
$database_mus_db = "musdb2";
$username_mus_db = "root";
$password_mus_db = "";

$tf=@mysql_connect($hostname_mus_db,$username_mus_db,$password_mus_db);
if(!$tf)
die('Connection problem1 ..');
$tf_db=mysql_select_db($database_mus_db);
if(!$tf_db)
{
 @mysql_close($tf_handle);
 die('selection problem2 ..');
}
$co_array=array();
if (isset($_GET['co'])) {
    $co=$_GET['co'];
       $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mha1 where id>".$co);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          $co_array[]=$row;
   }
    }
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array("date"=>$co_array));
?>
```

Comment: Throw in a couple of `Log.e()` into your code and see where the issues are popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your query is never executed because your url is malformed ( you put **>** instead of **=**), so the $_GET['co'] is never set, try by replacing

```
String url0 = ""http://172.17.100.2/sendapp.php?co>"+id_s;
```

By

```
String url0 = "http://172.17.100.2/sendapp.php?co="+id_s;
```

Comment: Now app after replacing it  display all the( id ,username ,image,email )in the row id1 ,id2,id3 etc
I want to display only the name from the last ID in the database thank u about your help

Comment: So you have to change the query To `SELECT name FROM mha1 where id>`  and then put just  this value in your json array or object

Comment: Can u editing my code please to display name from last id not from all id

Comment: What is the php result ?

Comment: Php result is "date "

Comment: sorry it is my fault, in the DB you have username instead of name? if so replace the query by `SELECT username FROM mha1 where id>`

Comment: yas I change with username and result was "date " , I researched meanytime in internet to found code like that but I don't found it .. I think my code is not right .. do u have code like that to do these mission

Comment: No sorry I don't have, try to print($co_array) to see what is contain